# Removing a div tag in variable of xsl file

Tags: xslt

I have to remove a div(menu) with an ul tag in it. All the data is stored in a variable **$data**. I have remove that div in that variable through xslt

Before:

```
<div id="container>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>         
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

After

```
<div id="container>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT is that? If XSLT 1.0, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: @MartinHonnen it's Xslt 1.0 in xsltproc

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know there is only the `div id="menu"` in that container `div` then you could make a shallow copy of that container `div`. In general, with XSLT 1.0, a variable will be a result tree fragment, to process it further with XSLT/XPath (other than outputting it with `value-of` or `copy-of`) you need to use `exsl:node-set` on the variable. Then you could process the elements with the identity transformation and a template for the `div[@id = 'menu']` that does not process it to delete it (online at http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9C):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="data">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>         
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="data2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($data)/node()"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="div[@id = 'menu']"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$data2"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

If you need to perform other transformation steps you might need to separate the different steps by using modes.